# ExtJS 4.0 Grid Date Column and Form Date Field (browser timezone issues)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, extjs, timezone

The Date Column in Grid (also in date form field) is using local browser time zone, but I prefer to use time zone selected in application user profile, rather than using browser timezone.

What can I do about it?

Can I forse ExtJS to use timezone without daylight saving time, so all the date/time combinations are valid like UTC? And which datetime format to use when comunicating with serverside?

I'm using PostgreSQL and also i'm not sure what database column type to use? Now I'm using timestamp with timezone, but not sure if its ok?

Answer (score 1):

In your EXT code, instead of specifying the date as `new Date()`, calculate the required date and use: `new Date("October 13, 2011 11:13:00")` (or whatever your preferred date is). You can do this using `convert:` in your field definitions.

**EDIT:** I would assume that the Date column in your grid gets its value from your database, correct? To adjust this you can use the "convert:" function in your field definition and add three hours (or whatever value you need).

```
{
   name: 'EventDate',
   type: 'date', dateFormat: "Y-m-d G:i:s", <-- adjust as needed
   convert: function(val) {
      return Ext.Date.add(val, Ext.Date.HOUR, 3)
   }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that because my browser timezone is Bulgaria/Sofia I can't display/input datetime 2011-03-27T03:00:00 because this is when the clocks here are moved 1 hour in advance. And ExtJS is using browser timezone internaly to display/parse dates (I think so) But the user may want to use different timezone from browser, so 2011-03-27T03:00:00 have to be a valid value. Also when the server return a datetime it can't know which timezone browser is using.

Comment: Or I just don't understand what you are saying to me :) I can also use a date and time separate fields ... may be this can help

Comment: I can adjust it (to correct database value), but still can't show 2011-03-27 03:00:00 in grid field because it's not a valid Date() in JavaScript when browser datefield is using Bulgarian TimeZone. It will show it as 2011-03-27 02:00:00 because that's when the currect time is shifting. See this: http://a.yfrog.com/img737/8836/7a6s.png

Comment: That's a tricky one - if you put it one second later, will it be correct?

Comment: It's still not correct :( http://a.yfrog.com/img619/4412/93br.png May be I need to implement my own field :( Not sure why Sencha made it this way (using JS Date variable) I need to switch off this browser timezone dependent behavior

Comment: May be I can tell ExtJS and/or JavaScript to use UTC timezone (there are no daylight saving days)?

Comment: It is always extremely tricky during the exact hour when daylight saving time begins (or ends) especially if you are in the world of browsers and javascript. I am not sure if this helps but there is an extension to the JavaScript Date artifact that can handle timezone information. Find it here: https://github.com/mde/timezone-js.